# How to download Server files into client system using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string filePath1 = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
string filepath = ("D:\\RetailAgreement\\" + filePath1);
FileInfo myfile = new FileInfo(filepath);
if (filePath1 != "")
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(myfile.Extension.ToLower());
    Response.TransmitFile(myfile.FullName);
    Response.End();

}
```

I tried like this but it is not working ,
I don't know where i went wrong. I am using C#3.0

Comment: Move (those files you want to download) files under your webapp and use `Server.MapPath` method to obtain real path.

Comment: How are you calling this code? You have presented us with a javascritp error yet no javascript. Is this an AJAX call? If so you are mistaken that you can down load a file like this. The page headers are already set, AJAX won't do that and expects a very different response.

Comment: this isn't a hard task. you don't need to play with response that much. take a look at http://rachelappel.com/upload-and-download-files-using-asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/DownloadedExcelFilesOp4/myfile.xlsx");
            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            string Outgoingfile = "myfile.xlsx";
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Outgoingfile);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Copy("D:\\RetailAgreement\\",Server.Mapth("YourAplicationPath\\MyFiles"), true);
//Copy Files to Your Application Path
string path = Server.MapPath("~\MyFiles" + filePath1");
            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            string Outgoingfile = "myfile.xlsx";
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Outgoingfile);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
            }
```